Calculated Column - Large Nested IF for progression through Status
I am trying to do a calculated column for Status with a large number of statuses and can't get it to work, grateful for any assistance.
I am trying to achieve this:
If today's date is less than \[Date1\] then \[Status1\]   
If today's date is between \[Date1\] and \[Date2\] then \[Status2\]
If today's date is after \[Date2\] and \[Column1\] is blank then \[Status3\]
If \[Column1\] is filled then \[Status4\]
If \[Column2\] is Yes then \[Status5\] (otherwise it remains at \[Status4\])
If today's date is between \[Date3\] and \[Date4\] then \[Status6\]
If today's date is after \[Date4\] then \[Status7\]

I need today's date to always be today's date, not calculated on modification.
The formula I have is below but it's not working. Grateful for any advice:
                IF(NOW()<[Date1],”Status1”,
                    IF(AND(NOW()>[Date1],(NOW()<[Date2],”Status2”),
                        IF(AND(NOW()>[Date2],ISBLANK[Column1],”Status3”),
                            IF([Column1]<>””,”Status4”,
                                IF([Column2]=Yes,”Status5”,
                                    IF(AND(NOW()>[Date3],NOW()<[Date4],”Status6”),
                                        IF(NOW()> [Date4],”Status7”,”Status1”
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )

